# AngularJS iterate linearly over a matrix of objects

Tags: loops, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know about the ng-repeat option, and my first solution was to create a table with rows and cells for the rows and columns of the matrix like so:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in matrix">
        <td class="tile" ng-repeat="tile in row">
            {{do tile.things}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but now I want a more flexible solution in which I set an offset in top, left on a 'position: absolute' element, which will not work this way of iterating through the rows and then the cells.

```
<div class="relative">
    <div ng-repeat="row in matrix">
        <span ng-repeat="cell in row">
            <span style="top: {{cell.topOffset}}%; left: {{cell.leftOffset}}%;">
                {{other cell.things}}
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason is that the 'position: absolute' is relative to the element in which it is nested, which is not the relatively positioned div container.

Is there a way to iterate over the rows and cells in one ng-repeat statement? Thus iterating linearly over the matrix instead of in two iterations?

My initial thought was that I need to write my own directive to do this, but I'm hoping there is an easier way...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides in that the percentages are always calculated on the parent element, not on the "relative" ancestor. The position, yes, the sizes, not.

So you really need to unroll the loop, and angular is not able to do it. You can use `underscore.js` or `lodash.js` for it. Include it, publish to the scope

```
angular.module('yourApp').run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope._ = _;
})
```

and flatten your double array before looping:

```
<div class="relative">
    <div ng-repeat="cell in _.flatten(matrix, 1)">
        <span style="top: {{cell.topOffset}}%; left: {{cell.leftOffset}}%;">
            {{other cell.things}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should also be sure that you apply CSS positions correctly. An `absolute` element is always positioned relatively to the nearest (containing) `relative` element.

Comment: Thanks, but this would be the same as using a function of angular (or just javascript) to unroll the loop, right? Yes, 'underscore.js' or 'lodash.js' have these functions included, but that is working around the problem. 
If this is the only solution, then this is the anwser, but I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if others have an even better understanding of angular

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 'position:absolute' is not relative to the element in which it is nested.  'position:absolute' is relative to the first ancestor which has a 'position:relative' or 'position:absolute' style.

Your should be able to get your more flexible solution should work, so long as you're not positioning the row divs.

Comment: i'll check this, still wondering if / why this is not working... Then again, i'm still interested in a way to iterate linearly over a matrix ;)

Comment: Yeah, your question is interesting.  I don't think you can combine mulitple ng-repeats on a single element.  I think you'll have to write a function to flatten the nested arrays and then iterate over that.

Comment: In the OP's problem, the 'absolute' positioning are not the problem, much more the percentage calculations for the positions. Which depend on the container, not on the positioning anchor.

Comment: That's a good observation.  I was merely noting that his assertion in the question was incorrect.  If he changes the vertical positioning to be a pixel value instead of a percentage, he should be able to get it working.